# boost::asio acceptor avoid memory leak

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

Using boost::asio i use async_accept to accept connections. This works good, but there is one issue and i need a suggestion how to deal with it. Using typical async_accept:

```
  Listener::Listener(int port)
        : acceptor(io, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port))
        , socket(io) {
          start_accept();
  }

  void Listener::start_accept() {
      Request *r = new Request(io);
      acceptor.async_accept(r->socket(), 
        boost::bind(&Listener::handle_accept, this, r, placeholders::error));
  }
```

Works fine but there is a issue: **Request** object is created with plain **new** so it can memory "leak". Not really a leak, it leaks only at program stop, but i want to make *valgrind* happy.

Sure there is an option: i can replace it with **shared_ptr**, and pass it to every event handler. This will work until program stop, when asio **io_service** is stopping, all objects will be destroyed and **Request** will be free'd. But this way i always must have an active asio event for **Request**, or it will be destroyed! I think its direct way to crash so i dont like this variant, too.

UPD Third variant: `Listener` holds list of shared_ptr to active connections. Looks great and i prefer to use this unless some better way will be found. The drawback is: since this schema allows to do "garbage collection" on idle connects, its not safe: removing connection pointer from Listener will immediately destroy it, what can lead to segfault when some of connection's handler is active in other thread. Using mutex cant fix this cus in this case we must lock nearly anything.

Is there a way to make **acceptor** work with connection management some beautiful and safe way? I will be glad to hear any suggestions.

Comment: Isn't this a problem with the design of your `Listener` class, or maybe with your strategy of using `bind` with a pointer rather than a function object, rather than a problem with the `acceptor` class?

Comment: Its not a function object=) But anyway i dont see how plain function can solve this..

Comment: @PSIAlt Can you please elaborate on why the idiomatic `shared_ptr`/`enable_shared_from_this` approach will not work?  I do not understand the context of *an active* asio event.  Also, if `Request` is not creating its own asynchronous call chain, and bindings its lifespan to the chain, then are other objects maintaining a handle to the `Request` object?

Comment: @twsansbury as "active asio event" i mean some pending async_read/async_write or whatever what hold shared_ptr to keep connection object alive. About `Request` object storage - its good variant but with drawbacks too; i added it to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical recipe for avoiding memory leaks when using this library is using a `shared_ptr`, the `io_service` [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/_io_service.html) specifically mentions this

> Remarks
>
> The destruction sequence described above permits programs to simplify
>   their resource management by using `shared_ptr<>`. Where an object's
>   lifetime is tied to the lifetime of a connection (or some other
>   sequence of asynchronous operations), a `shared_pt`r to the object would
>   be bound into the handlers for all asynchronous operations associated
>   with it. This works as follows:
>
> When a single connection ends, all associated asynchronous operations
>   complete. The corresponding handler objects are destroyed, and all
>   shared_ptr references to the objects are destroyed. To shut down the
>   whole program, the `io_service` function `stop()` is called to terminate
>   any `run()` calls as soon as possible. The io_service destructor defined
>   above destroys all handlers, causing all `shared_ptr` references to all
>   connection objects to be destroyed.

For your scenario, change your `Listener::handle_accept(`) method to take a `boost::shared_ptr<Request>` parameter. Your second concern

> removing connection pointer from Listener will immediately destroy it,
>   what can lead to segfault when some of connection's handler is active
>   in other thread. Using mutex cant fix this cus in this case we must
>   lock nearly anything.

is mitigated by inheriting from the `boost::enable_shared_from_this` template in your classes:

```
class Listener : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Listener>
{
   ...
};
```

then when you dispatch handlers, use `shared_from_this()` instead of `this` when binding to member functions of `Listener`.

Comment: As i mentioned, in this case where connection cannot exist without active async events, what is bad for me cus i have to deal with other async connection (getting data) to deal with every request, so time when i getting data use connection is idle and not events on it

Comment: @PSIAlt I've updated my answer, you want to use `shared_from_this()`.

Comment: Thanks for help, ill try this one, seems resonable

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested, i found another way. `Listener` holds list of shared_ptr to active connections. Connections ending/terminating is made via `io_service::post` which call `Listener::FinishConnection` wrapped with `asio::strand`. Usually i always wrap Request's methods with strand - its safer in terms of DDOS and/or thread safety. So, calling `FinishConnection` from `post` using `strand` protects from segfault in other thread

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this is directly related to your issue, but I was also having similar memory leaks by using the *Boost Asio* libraries, in particular the same `acceptor` object you mentioned. Turned out that I was not shutting down the service correctly; some connections would stay opened and their corresponding objects would not be freed from memory. Calling the following got rid of the leaks reported by *Valgrind*:

```
acceptor.close();
```

Hope this can be useful for someone!